# Machine architecture or computer architecture

Tags: architecture

Please what is the difference between machine archictechture and computer architechture . Berkley give a webcast on machine architecture and I am thinking it might be related to computer architecture am I correct.

If not is this same thing about system architechture (i.e machine structure and system architecture)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can recall from my GCSE science lessons, a machine is something that takes a force and changes that force's direction or magnitude.

In this context, Machine Architecture would refer to designing force altering mechanisms. This may be relevant to you interests as it could provide insight into design principles.

A computer could be seen as a complex set of interacting machines, if the above definition is correct (I'm recalling from 14 years ago, my memory isn't great).

In fact [this definition](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=computer) states that a computer is a machine for automatically permforming calculations.

I'm not familiar with the Berkley webcast you refer to, however "machine" is often used as a colloquialism for computer, and so the webcast could indeed be about computer architecture.

Your best bet is to watch the webcast, you have nothing to lose and you could learn something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is little difference.

Use of the phrase "machine architecture" implies a reference to a specific computer implementation, such as a desktop computer.

Use of the phrase "computer architecture" implies a general reference to the architecture of computers.

In both, "architecture" refers to the design and structure of a computer system.